# How to restore PDF from ASCII?

Tags: ascii, restore

I have a question, how to restore PDF file, if all I have is the only ASCII output?

Example:

```
%PDF-1.3
%���������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x�ѽ
�0�ݧ8O�����[�AAqp� �jK|{S�"�f�2���[�
�(M@���#�FFIw�=*��?J4'�P�y^TP`�Q�
+�i�E�8ψ�g���º��(6�֭,���s0�T��ZL�~�e�.EA��`J�f��<��M�

[...]

0000120481 00000 n
0000122448 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 94 /Root 57 0 R /Prev 116103 /Info 1 0 R>>
startxref
122488
%%EOF
```

It's the beginning and end of output I have and I need to restore it back into a readable form. I tried a few things, but I was unlucky.

Comment: Just save it as a file with a .pdf extension?

Comment: I modified code a little bit. And yes, I tried it, but nothing happend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible, the information was lost.

You can't represent binary data as a printable text using ASCII encoding in the 'One Byte' to 'One Char' ratio.

There are many non-printable characters in the ASCII table that could be supressed when converting the pdf binary file contents, destroying the original data.

Quoted-Printable encoding and Base64 encoding are more suitable for such application.

Check this out: [Binary-to-text_encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding)

Comment: Lost? So, when I use hexdump on some PDF file, like - 'hexdump -C file.pdf', then I grep only ASCII output with intention to restore it back into PDF, it's impossible? Yeah, I had also one PDF file, which is transfering in POST data and encoded with base64, in this case, I can restore it easily...

Comment: hexdump -C converts the binary data to its Base16 representation, in this case, you can restore it.